# insert from another table and then link tables by id

Tags: mysql, insert

I need to refactor a Company table so that the address information is moved into a dedicated Address table.

So I figure I need to do something like this to create the new address records.

```
INSERT INTO address (city, country, ...)
SELECT city,country, ... FROM company
```

But how do I update the company table with the id of the newly created address records in order to maintain referential integrity?

There are several duplicate addresses so I cant just join on the city, country fields, etc.

UPDATE

As alluded to by juergen d, the way I got round this is to create a temporary company_id column in the address table:

```
ALTER TABLE address ADD company_id INTEGER

INSERT INTO address (city,country,company_id)
SELECT city,country,id from company

UPDATE company c set c.address_id = (select a.id from address a where a.company_id = c.id)

ALTER TABLE address DROP COLUMN company_id;
```

Comment: Afterwards use `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the ID of the new record

Comment: will LAST_INSERT_ID() not just give me the id of the last record inserted by the statement, regardless of how many have been inserted?

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `company_id` in your `address` table.

```
INSERT INTO address (company_id, city, country, ...)
SELECT id, city, country, ... 
FROM company
```

Then there is no need to add any `address_id` to the `company` table.

Comment: My database design is better suited to the company being the owning side of the relationship. But what I can do is create the company_id column temporarily, do the insert as you suggest, and then update the company table using the company_id column before deleting it. See my update.